# Spark/Scala - Validate JSON document in a row of a streaming DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a streaming application which is processing a streaming DataFrame with column "body" that contains a JSON string.

So in the body is something like (these are four input rows):

```
{"id":1, "ts":1557994974, "details":[{"id":1,"attr2":3,"attr3":"something"}, {"id":2,"attr2":3,"attr3":"something"}]}
{"id":2, "ts":1557994975, "details":[{"id":1,"attr2":"3","attr3":"something"}, {"id":2,"attr2":"3","attr3":"something"},{"id":3,"attr2":"3","attr3":"something"}]}
{"id":3, "ts":1557994976, "details":[{"id":1,"attr2":3,"attr3":"something"}, {"id":2,"attr2":3}]}
{"id":4, "ts":1557994977, "details":[]}
```

I would like to check that each row has the correct schema (data types and contains all attributes). I would like to filter out and log the invalid records somewhere (like a Parquet file). I am especially interested in the "details" array - each of the nested documents must have specified fields and correct data types.

So in the example above only row id = 1 is valid.

I was thinking about a case class such as:

```
case class Detail(
  id: Int,
  attr2: Int,
  attr3: String
)

case class Input(
  id: Int,
  ts: Long,
  details: Seq[Detail]
)
```

and Try but not sure how to go about it.

Could someone help, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) that can help you with schema validations on the data. The [getting started](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html) page is a good place to start off with if you're new.

The other approach would roughly work as follows

1. Build models (case classes) for each of the objects like you've attempted in your question.
2. Use a JSON library like [Spray JSON](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) / [Play-JSON](https://github.com/playframework/play-json) to parse the input json.
3. For all input that fail to be parsed into valid records mostly likely invalid and you can partition those output into a different sink in your spark code. It would also make this robust if you've an `isValid` method on the objects which can validate if a parsed record is correct or not too.

Comment: Thanks, looking at spray-json but not sure how do I parse  each row in the dataframe?

Comment: Given the input has an `body: String` which is a json, you can use the spray code listed on the Usages section of the README (https://github.com/spray/spray-json#usage) to parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me is to create a Dataframe with a Schema and then filter with `id == 1`. This is not the most efficient way.

Heare you can find a example to create a dataframe with Schema: https://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2016/01/30/processing-json-data-with-sparksql/

**Edit**
I can't find a Pre-filtering to speed up JSON search in scala, but you can use this three options:

```
spark.read.schema(mySchema).format(json).load("myPath").filter($"id" === 1)
```

or

```
spark.read.schema(mySchema).json("myPath").filter($"id" === 1)
```

or

```
spark.read.json("myPath").filter($"id" === 1)
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm probably missing the obvious but what is "pid"? And yes I would appreciate if you could show the most efficient way. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it's `id`, not `pid` I added a char of more, now it's edited and I will try a more efficient way and edit again.

Comment: @t138 I edited the respond, if doesn't work for your example, please you will tell me.