# Validating Schema of Column with StructType in Pyspark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that has a column that is a JSON string

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

l = [
    (1, """{"key1": true, "nested_key": {"mylist": ["foo", "bar"], "mybool": true}})"""),
    (2, """{"key1": true, "nested_key": {"mylist": "", "mybool": true}})"""),
    ]
df = sc.createDataFrame(l, ["id", "json_str"])
```

and want to parse the `json_str` column with `from_json` using a schema

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("key1", BooleanType(), False),
    StructField("nested_key", StructType([
        StructField("mylist", ArrayType(StringType()), False),
        StructField("mybool", BooleanType(), False)
     ]))
])

df = df.withColumn("data", F.from_json(F.col("json_str"), schema))
df.show(truncate=False)
+---+--------------------------+
|id |data                      |
+---+--------------------------+
|1  |[true, [[foo, bar], true]]|
|2  |[true, [, true]]          |
+---+--------------------------+
```

As one can see, the second row didn't conform to the schema in `schema` so it's null even though I passed `False` to `nullable` in the StructField. It's important to my pipeline that if there's data that doesn't conform to the schema defined that an alert get raised somehow, but I'm not sure about the best way to do this in Pyspark. The real data has many, many keys, some of them nested so checking each one with some form of `isNan` isn't feasable and since we already defined the schema it feels like there should be away to leverage that.

If it matters, I don't necessarily need to check the schema of the whole dataframe, I'm really after checking the schema of the StructType column

Comment: This seems to be still an open issue. The only way I could find to validate a custom JSON is via custom Readers/Writers as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164294/spark-scala-validate-json-document-in-a-row-of-a-streaming-dataframe/56187190#56187190) please check the footnote :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `options` parameter: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=from_json#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json

It's a little vague, but it allows you to pass a `dict` to the underlying method here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=from_json#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json

You might have success passing something like `options={'mode' : 'FAILFAST'}`.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and a solid find, but I tried that on the example in the post and it didn't work